# combine SELECTS in ONE VIEW DISPLAY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know of a way to combine multiple SELECT statements in one VIEW?  I tried the UNION ALL, but it fails since I am using unique columns to aggregate the GRAND TOTAL.
I am a student this is part of a group project.

I have one table with 4 columns: account, description, short_description, and balance. The COA (chart of accounts) is an excel spreadsheet that is imported.

```
CREATE VIEW [account_balance_sums]
AS
  SELECT SUM(balance) AS total,   
  SUBSTRING (Account,0,2) AS account_group
    FROM COA
    GROUP BY account_group
GO


 SELECT * FROM [account_balance_sums]
 SELECT SUM(total) AS Grand_total
 FROM [account_balance_sums]
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Create and display a VIEW that displays the account balance subtotals for each account group.  Account group is defined as the first two digits of the account number.  Display a grand total of the balance column at the end of the display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to create a view that gives account group and total balance with a single extra row for the total across all accounts then this view should help:

```
CREATE VIEW [account_balance_sums] AS
  SELECT SUM(balance) AS total, SUBSTRING (Account,0,2) AS account_group
    FROM COA
   GROUP BY account_group
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(balance), 'Grand Total'
    FROM account_group
```

By the way, the sub-string of the first characters of the account name suggests that you have more than one piece of data in a single column. This indicates a data that is not properly normalised, which you should probably address if you want top marks. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) on normal form

Answer (score 1):

In a UNION'd statement, there must be:

1. The same number of columns in each SELECT statement
2. The data types must match at each position in the SELECT statement

Use:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [account_balance_sums]
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(total),
       NULL AS account_group
  FROM [account_balance_sums]
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION ALL should work.  basic structure like this

```
select a,b,c,d 
from t1
union all 
select a,b,c,e
from t2
```

so long as d and e are the same data type.

to do the sum, then you wrap this with the aggregation layer - using this structure as an inline view (among other methods)

something like:

```
select sum( d )
from (
    select a,b,c,d 
    from t1
    union all 
    select a,b,c,e
    from t2
)
```